# How to implement the "match" path concept from Rails into PHP?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails

In particular I have the following in the app's config/routes.rb file:

```
match "/:id" => "UrlDB#userreq"
```

And in the UrlDBController is:

```
def userreq
    @request = UrlDB.find_by_url( (params[:id] )
end
```

I would like to be able to have the same userreq method respond to all incoming requests regards of what the :id value is - I don't know how to implement this in PHP/Apache.

-daniel

Comment: This will vary from framework to framework. PHP itself has no concept of routes - you'll either have to use a framework (which one?), or build your own routing

Comment: Rails is a Ruby framework for web applications. In PHP you'd probably also want to use some kind of framework, and the solution would depend on which framework you choose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, Rails is a Ruby framework, and PHP is a language. To get the same functionality in PHP you have to use a framework, as you do with Ruby.

Or you can do it by hands:

The old way of doing this without using any framework, is by using Apache rewrite rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /(\d+) userreq.php?id=$1
```

An other way is to do this manually in PHP, still with some help from Apache.

In Apache config / .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule . - [L]
```

And in index.php:

```
$path = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if (preg_match('#/(\d+)#', $path, $match)) {
    // execute userreq controller
} else if (preg_match(...)) {
...
```

Comment: Thanks.  That's the answer I need.  I should have stated that whole point of wanting the conversion was because I don't want to use a framework at all ... old school, broken and insecure, but there it is ...

Answer (score 0):

PHP gives you freedom about it. You are not forced to use "some concept of routing" (like in Rails), you can use "any concept of routing". You are not even forced to use "controller" nor the MVC model.

Simply get incoming parameters (using $_REQUEST), and decide "routing" by your own.

Or - use any existing framework - most of them define some "routing" template/engine.